# same matrix with different decimal rules

Tags: r, matrix, decimal, output

I am working on a function to do my own output from some linear models and i am wanting to make a matrix of output i am trying to get a matrix with different decimal rules. for example if i have:

```
structure(c(1, 2, 3.45, 5.67), .Dim = c(4L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), NULL))'
```

is it possible to make rows 1 and 2 just show up as integers and the decimals stay in the last two rows? i know i could make two matrices and use rbind() but i want to keep the alignment the same so the columns line up well.

Comment: No. R matrices need to be atomic, i.e. all of the same storage mode: (No mixed data types.). The only way to achieve your goal would be to make a new class that has a different print method.

Comment: ok thanks, focus on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy if you transform your numeric matrix into a character matrix before printing:

```
print("[<-"(mat, as.character(mat)), quote = FALSE)
```

This displays:

```
  [,1]
A 1   
B 2   
C 3.45
D 5.67
```

This above command is similar to:

```
mat[] <- as.character(mat)
print(mat, quote = FALSE)
```

but keeps `mat` unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Output in R is formatted using the `print(...)` function; use the digits= parameter to control the number of significant digits in the output.

So, if your matrix above is `M`:

```
print(M[1:2,],digits=0)
# A B 
# 1 2 
print(M[3:4,],digits=3)
#    C    D 
# 3.45 5.67
```

Comment: the issue here is i want one matrix for all values as my row names are different lengths, so i am trying to make a function that makes the output from linear models with information how i want it (and learning more about R programming) and i want a vector of values with the row names as different labels of the values.